# How to get the currentUser provided by spring security in Grails 2 unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spring-security, mocking

Hi guys i am on trouble about getting the current user provided by spring.

Here's my unit test code

```
   void "Test if adding project will sucess"() {

    given:
        def createProjectMock = mockFor(UserService)

        createProjectMock.demand.createNewProject { Map projectMap ->
            return true
        }

        controller.userService = createProjectMock.createMock()

    when: "saveProject is execute"

        controller.saveProject()

    then: "page will to the list to view the saved project"
        response.redirectedUrl == '/user/index2'
}
```

Here's my controller

```
def saveProject(ProjectActionCommand projectCmd) {

  def currentUser = springSecurityService.currentUser
  if (projectCmd.hasErrors()) {

    render view: 'createProject', model: [projectInstance: projectCmd, user:currentUser]
  } else {

    def getProjectMap = [:]

    getProjectMap = [
      projectName: params.projectName,
      user: currentUser
    ]

    def saveProject = userService.createNewProject(getProjectMap)

    if (saveProject) {   

      redirect view: 'index2'         
    } else {
      render 'Error upon saving'
    }
  }
}
```

And here's my service

```
  Project createNewProject(Map projectMap){
    def createProject = new Project()

    createProject.with {
      projectName = projectMap.projectName
      user = projectMap.user
    }

    createProject.save(failOnError:true, flush: true)
  }
```

And i always getting this error:

Cannot get property 'currentUser' on null object.

Hope you can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot get property 'currentUser' on null object.

means that you haven't mocked springSecurityService. Let's do it in setup section (I assume it may be useful also in other methods in this class):

```
def springSecurityService

def setup() {
    springSecurityService = Mock(SpringSecurityService)
    controller.springSecurityService = springSecurityService
}
```

At this point your code is going to work. However remember that you can always mock also the actual logged user and test it at any point:

```
    User user = Mock(User)
    springSecurityService.currentUser >> user
```